# iPhone screen size 4 pushes button down

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Every time that I setup a layout for iPhone 4 and switch view for iPhone 5 it pushes all the buttons down and messes up my layout how do I prevent this? For example,Say if a button in the middle of the iPhone 4 if I switch to iPhone 5 screen size, it is at the bottom.

Comment: You should use auto layout or auto resizing for views in IB

Comment: @moo Did any of the three answers helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go the the size tab and change rthe red struts to anchor to the top instead of bottom.

iOS6 has another option: auto layout, it can be disabled if desired or if compatubility with iOS5 and below is needed.

[image]

Comment: @Moo is using iOS not Mac OS :(

Comment: Basically the same, replace with an iOS screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the button's frame position based on the height of the view it's in.  Use the views frame in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```